# Why do not I observe the variables that I create in spyder?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, slice, spyder

I am working with spyder and have the Python version: `3.5.2 Anaconda custom (64-bit)`
At the beginning I import all libraries I need:

```
import numpy as np
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
```

specify the path and upload the dataset:

```
os.chdir('C:\\Users\\...\\Data_Preprocessing')
dataset = pd.read_csv('Data.csv')
```

I can observe my dataset in variable explorer window. But when I try to create the matrix of my independent variables with commands like:

```
X = dataset.ix[:, :-1].values
```

or

```
X = dataset.iloc[:, :-1].values
```

I get:

> Exception in thread Thread-1:
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users...\lib\threading.py", line 914, in _bootstrap_inner
>       self.run()
>     File "C:\Users...\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\monitor.py", line 569, in run
>       self.update_remote_view()
>     File "C:\Users...\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\monitor.py", line 450, in update_remote_view
>       remote_view = make_remote_view(ns, settings, more_excluded_names)
>     File "C:\Users...\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\monitor.py", line 79, in make_remote_view
>       minmax=settings['minmax'])
>     File "C:\Users...\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\dicteditorutils.py", line 225, in value_to_display
>       return display
>   UnboundLocalError: local variable 'display' referenced before assignment

I can still calculate all what I need, but I do not observe created variables in variable explorer. How can I observe them and Why is it happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*Spyder developer here*) This is a bug and it was fixed in Spyder **2.3.9**. Please update to fix it.